# can sbrk(0) fail?

Tags: c, glibc, sbrk

I'd like to know if someone already seen sbrk(0) fail ?

I mean, if you can reach this function you obviously had the rights to access the memory before, so to check the current break location should be ok, right ?

EDIT : Should I consider an error exception for example ?

Comment: I take it it failed for you?

Comment: The way I'm using it had never guide me to an error at least.

Comment: What's funny is that according to the loose wording of the documentation, it acutally _could_ fail. Which is, of course, complete nonsense.

Comment: The Mac OS X documentation for `sbrk(2)` says: _The current value of the program break is reliably returned by ``sbrk(0)``_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documents](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) states that:

```
   sbrk() increments the program's data space by increment bytes.
   Calling sbrk() with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current
   location of the program break.

  ...

   On success, sbrk() returns the previous program break.  (If the break
   was increased, then this value is a pointer to the start of the newly
   allocated memory).  On error, (void *) -1 is returned, and errno is
   set to ENOMEM.
```

If you look at [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/sbrk.c) implementation you will see:

```
extern void *__curbrk;
  ...
void *
__sbrk (intptr_t increment)
{
  ...
  if (increment == 0)
    return __curbrk; 
  ...
```

there is no way it will fail since it just returns the current value of `__curbrk` if `increment` is zero.

Comment: Ye thanks a lot finally got it.
Took a look on 

http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.18/sysdeps_2mach_2hurd_2brk_8c_source.html

too :)